Personal settings periodically disappear
This week I installed the OS on an external Hard Disk, running a Dell laptop.
I installed some applications,and loaded some documents.
I changed some OS settings (for example screen resolution), set up Firefox, Thunderbird, mapped remote folders, Google Drive, etc. with no issue.
Periodically all my OS and application settings disappear. The OS return to original default settings. However all my files and folders remain untouched.
I had the issues twice already.
Do you know what would be the cause of issue, and how to resolve it, please?.
